# DOCKER COMPOSE python: can't open file '/app/app.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I try to use docker-compose up, but there is an errno 2

I want to use docker compose, but there is error like this:

```
python: can't open file '/app/app.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

**Directory path**

**/Assignment6**

- docker.compose.yml
- dockerfile
- Makefile
- requirements.txt

**/Assignment6/app**

- app.py
- book.py
- borrow.py
- return_book.py
- utils.py

My Dockerfile contains:

```sh
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN python3.9 -m pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY app .


CMD ["flask", "--app". "app.py", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]`
```

`docker-compose.yml` contains:

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
  library-db:
    image: "postgres:14"
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_HOST: ${POSTGRES_HOST}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      POSTGRES_PORT: ${POSTGRES_PORT}

  library:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
    env_file: .env
    depends_on:
      - library-db
```

Comment: if your WORKDIR is `/app`, and you run the command `COPY app .`, it will copy the folder `app` into the destination `/app/app`. So the file is likely at `/app/app/app.py`. If you want app in your root, you should run this from root, or you could run `COPY app /`

Comment: i already change COPY app . to COPY app / 
but it has same output error

Comment: Can you update the question to reflect what you’re doing?

Comment: I tried COPY app . with my pc and the files are copied as aspected inside /app, so your CMD should work because when you run CMD you are already inside /app folder. Are you sure you have correctly re-builded your dockefile image? try this "docker-compose up -d --build".
However you can try 'CMD ["ls"]' and see logs for understand where are your files. Note: you will see files specified in your WORKDIR path